# Booting Ubuntu 20.04 on Intel CPU causes reboot

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

I just bought a new setup

MB: ASUS Prime B460-PLUS LGA 1200 (Intel 10th Gen) ATX Motherboard

CPU: Intel Core i5-10600K

Installing a fresh copy of Ubuntu 20.04. Using the onboard VGA.

The computer consistently reboots in normal graphics mode.  I can only run in safe graphics mode.

I installed the mesa drivers.

Comment: Which kernel? I had difficulties with an i5-10600K and 20.04 kernels and had to switch to 20.04 HWE (newer) kernels.

Comment: 5.11.0-18 generic

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 20.04 currently comes with the 5.8 (1st HWE Kernel for 20.04) Kernel. You must have somehow installed 5.11 (2nd HWE kernel for 20.04) manually, 5.11 will only be used by default around the 20.04.3 update (~August 2021).

Also on Ubuntu on Intel or AMD there is virtually never a need to “install Mesa drivers”, they come with Ubuntu and are automatically updated and managed. If you need newer Mesa you can install a PPA, but that isn’t recommend or supported, and PPAs can absolutely cause problems like this one.

I would generally recommend not using VGA, but it should still work. If possible try out other ports on your motherboard.

Please try Ubuntu 21.04 which comes with a newer Kernel and Mesa by default, no configuration required. If that works perhaps try 20.04 again, ensuring you go for a very “default” installation.

Comment: I mis-spoke.    I thought I had installed 20.04,  but I selected 21.04.  I do have 21.04.  I only installed the mesa drivers after doing some google searches.  it was mentioned in an old post.  I have since re-installed the default 21.04. and no additional drivers.   Same problems.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 is fairly recent so I doubt it’s a software issue.
Can you try using the HDMI port on your motherboard?

Can you confirm you 100% have the Intel Core i5-10600K and not the i5-10600KF? The F suffix means that there is no integrated graphics on the CPU, which would cause your issue.

Could you tell if graphics were being used during installation? Or were you in safe graphics mode (i.e. no gpu acceleration).

As a last resort I’d suggest trying another distro like fedora workstation 34. If that still doesn’t work try booting windows and seeing if that works.

Comment: This is the processor I bought https://www.amazon.com/dp/B086MHSH2C?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2_dt_b_product_details   The HDMI port gives the same result.  During install I believe it was only in safe graphics mode,  low res.    I have no windows install media to test.   I did end up putting an old nvidia gt630 card in just So I could have a working computer.  That works fine.  For now I'll leave it .  Based on some ubuntu forum chats,  there seems to be an issue with intel graphics anyway.

Comment: Glad to hear you have a working computer now, sorry I couldn’t be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by not using Intel Graphics.  Used old NVidia card.

its not a perfect solution,  but it gives me a working computer.